# Tooltip display on top without affecting the height and width of container

Tags: css, reactjs

On click on the image, number displays as `tooltip` message for 4 seconds and disappears. This is working as expected. But while displaying the tooltip, the `div` height and width got changed. How can we display the tool tip on top of the image without affecting the height/width of the `grid-container`

I haved added a demo here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-ellis-2h3pd?file=/src/components/Home.js

Comment: If you could include your CSS and HTML into the link, that would be great, and would help SO users find the answer faster.

Comment: `css` is already avaiable under the `styles.css` in that link.

Comment: Sorry, I am not used to the CodeSandbox platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution**

You can set `position: absolute` and apply necessary margins to make it appear on top of the image

```
{phoneTooltip === id && (
  <div style={{position: 'absolute', marginLeft: '100px', zIndex: 1, marginTop: '-50px'}} 
    className="tooltip_PhoneNumber_home" key={phonenumber}>
      {phonenumber}
</div>
)}
```

**Second Solution**

Refactor jsx so tooltip is always on top of image but with `visibility: hidden`, `opacity: 0` and click action makes it visible.

```
<span className="phoneNumber_home">
  <div style={{opacity: phoneTooltip === id ? 1 : 0}} className="tooltip_PhoneNumber_home" key={phonenumber}>
    {phonenumber}
  </div>
  <img
    src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/tulips.png"
    alt={"phoneTooltip.show"}
    key={id}
    name="phoneNumberhomeicon"
    onClick={displayPhoneToolTip(id)}/>
</span>
```

Comment: Happy to say that height and width extension is not happening anymore. In desktop view it look good, but in mobile view its going out of the container.